# How to use a jQuery variable in a table selector

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
var t = <?php echo $t; ?>;
var id = "container" + t;
$('#container tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#container tbody>tr:last');
</script>
```

How do I code it to change #container to the variable id?

I have multiple table id's, incremented by t. Example, #container0, #container1, #container2, etc.

Comment: Why the hate (-3)? Just asked a simple question. I'm no JS expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string:

```
'#container tbody>tr:last'
```

And you want to replace part of that string with a variable.  You would use the `+` operator to concatenate string values.  Something like this:

```
'#' + id + ' tbody>tr:last'
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have figured it out. Just was spinning trying different things.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var t = <?php echo $t; ?>;
var id = "container" + t;
$('#' + id + ' tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#' + id + ' tbody>tr:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(id+' tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#container tbody>tr:last');
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
 var id = "container" + t;
 $('#'+id+' tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#'+id+' tbody>tr:last');
```

Comment: You need a space before tbody

Comment: ya. It was copy paste ;)